# Powershell Git Hook Exit Code

Tags: windows, git, bash, powershell

I have the following in my .git/hooks/pre-commit file

```
#!/bin/sh
exec c:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command " Get-Location | % { '$_\pre-commit-hook.ps1'} | % { & $_ }"
exit
```

This successfully executes the code in the `pre-commit-hook.ps1` file in the same directory, but does not capture the exit code. According to [tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) the last exit code will be returned if only exit is specified. Git hooks will fail if the exit code is non-zero, but even though my powershell script returns a status code of 1, it always succeeds. What can I do to capture the exit code from the powershell script so the hook will function correctly?

Comment: In your script try adding `[environment]::Exit(1)` to return the non-zero code to the caller. If this works i'll make it my answer :-)

Comment: nope doesn't work. I already had just `exit 1` in my script but that didn't work either

Comment: I figured you might of... Because sometimes it [doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902004/powershell-fails-to-return-proper-exit-code/8902329#8902329).

Comment: If you try just `exec c:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command "[environment]::Exit(1)"` does it work?

Comment: yeah that does work, but doesn't solve the problem lol. Would you mind going to chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/7875/matt?tab=general

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep the invocation of the ps1 script simple and you should have it working. The following works for me:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 
exec powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File '.\.git\hooks\pre-commit-hook.ps1'
exit
```

The ps1 script just had an `exit 1` and the commit did not happen.

When you are doing stuff like `-command`, Powershell is not known to work properly and you might have to do something like `-command {& .\test.ps1; exit $lastexitcode}`

Comment: Yup that works. I think the key here is that even though "pre-commit" itself is already running in .git/hooks, the current directory is the root of your project. That is definitely NOT in the docs ;)